# Search in two fields on elasticsearch with kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Assuming I have an index with two fields: `title` and `loc`, I would like to search in this two fields and get the "best" match. So if I have three items:

```
{"title": "castle", "loc": "something"},
{"title": "something castle something", "loc": "something,pontivy,something"},
{"title": "something else", "loc": "something"}
```

... I would like to get the second one which has `"castle"` in its `title` and `"pontivy"` in its `loc`. *I tried to simplify the example and the base, it's a bit more complicated.* So I tried this query, but it seems not accurate (it's a feeling, not really easy to explain):

```
GET merimee/_search/?
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "castle pontivy", 
      "fields": [ "title", "loc" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Is it the right way to search in various field and get the one which match the in all the fields?

Not sure my question is clear enough, I can edit if required.

EDIT:

The story is: the user type "castle pontivy" and I want to get the "best" result for this query, which is the second because it contains "castle" in "title" and "pontivy" in "loc". In other words I want the result that has the best result in both fields.

Comment: You can try 2 match and then use the logical AND operator

Comment: @Saramali Thank you! I'm not sure to understand, could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other posted suggested, you could use a bool query but that might not work for your use case since you have a single search box that you want to query against multiple fields with.

I recommend looking at a Simple Query String query as that will likely give you the functionality you're looking for. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html

So you could do something similar to this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "castle pontivy",
        "fields": ["title", "loc"],
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

So this will try to give you the best documents that match both terms in either of those fields. The default operator is set as AND here because otherwise it is OR which might not give you the expected results.

It is worthwhile to experiment with other options available for this query type as well. You might also explore using a Query String query as it gives more flexibility but the Simple Query String term works very well for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using bool type of query and then matching the fields.

```
  GET _search
  {
   "query": 
    {
     "bool": {"must": [{"match": {"title": "castle"}},{"match": {"loc": "pontivy"}}]
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! It will not work for my case because the actual query is `castle pontivy` so I don't know which word must mach which field... Sorry if it was not clear...

Comment: I don't understand. What fields are you trying to match and for what values.

Comment: Sorry. Story : the user type "castle pontivy" and I want to get the "best" result for this query, which is the second because it contains "castle" in "title" and "pontivy" in "loc". In other words I want the result that has the best result in both fields. Maybe it's stupid, I'm a beginner with elastic search

Comment: I don't understand. both of the fields can have 2 possible values which would be included in the best result?